# Screen starts flickering on external monitor connect

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I will copy and paste the question from ubuntuforums, as long as I haven't found the solution, but the problem the post describes is very clear.

"I've got a Lenovo z50-70 with an installation of Gnome 15.04 with nVidia GeForce 840M, my nvidia driver version is 346.59, the drivers were installed using the "Additional drivers".

When I connect an external monitor using the VGA or HDMI port the screens start to flicker, when one of them turns black the other flashes, they seem to be exchanging multiple times a second.

I've tried installing compizconfig settings manager and checking the checkbox under workarounds->force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint but it did not help, even after a restart.

when I try to switch to the Intel graphics card however, everything works fine.

How can I fix this?"

But instead, I have Ubuntu 14.04 and the latest nvidia driver 352.63.

[Post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2290977)